# How to simplify my arc length formula.

Tags: limits, soft-question, riemann-sum

When we use Riemann Sums to evaluate definite integrals, and tend the limit of width of the rectangle to zero, then the area become zero. 
If I use similar logic to evaluate arc length (not the traditional formula), by- 
$l^2=h^2+(f(x+h)-f(x))^2$, where $l$ is arc length, and do $$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \sqrt{h^2+(f(x+h)-f(x))^2}+\cdots+\sqrt{h^2+(f(x+nh)-f(x+(n-1)h))^2}$$ What will it be?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\not=0$ even though $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: What is $\displaystyle \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}_{n~\text{times}}$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: One??? It should be one only?

Comment: It's $n\times \frac{1}{n}=1$. Even though you think you're summing zeros you won't obtain zero. Because you're summing an infinite number of terms : $\underbrace{0+\cdots+0}_{\text{infinitely many zeros}}=0\times\infty$ which is an indeterminate form. Check [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).

Comment: I had thought about that, but how does this answer my problem. Ok, theoretically, the answer comes, but if you have a rectangle, you keep the length constant suppose $l$, and width suppose $w$, to $0$. So on tending $w$ to zero, $\lim\limits_{w\to0}l*w=0$

Comment: That's only true if you have a finite number of rectangles.

Comment: And why false, if infinite?

Comment: As I told you: for finite number of rectangles $0\times\text{a finite number}=0$ but for an infinite number of rectangles $0\times\infty$ is indeterminate, it could give anything.

Comment: You say: **it could give anything**. Then how is riemann sum giving the exact answer?

Comment: [Because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) it's a convergent series.

Comment: Your idea is correct that area of one such rectangle tends to $0$ as its width tends to $0$. But here in a Riemann sum, you don't have a limit of area of one rectangle, rather the limit is taken for the sum of all rectangles. The limit theorem $\lim \{a_{n} + b_{n}\} = \lim a_{n} + \lim b_{n}$ holds only if the number of terms in the sum is independent of $n$. In Riemann sum number of terms is always dependent on $n$ and we can't split the sum and take limits term by term.

Comment: So my arc length formula is also convergent, ain't it? Then what will be the limit?

Comment: The limit is the arclength of the curve. Of course you should specify $f(x)$.

Comment: Your sum is represented by $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1 + \{f'(x)\}^{2}}\,dx$ which is the arclength formula.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is $e^x$ from $4$ to $6$. Then?

Comment: I know the traditional formula, but how would you simplify mine?

Comment: Not all integrals can be expressed directly in explicit form. For your example the answer is $\int_{4}^{6}\sqrt{1 + e^{2x}}\,dx$ which has a numerical value which can be calculated if one wants to any level of accuracy.

Comment: The answer is [$348.84$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+4+to+6+of+sqrt%281%2Bexp%282x%29%29)

Comment: I said, can you do that by my formula?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Paramanand Singh just answered you.

Comment: Your formula is not a formula, but rather a crude definition of arc-length. A formula is normally an identity which simplifies calculation/evaluation. A definition might not be simple to calculate.

Comment: So can't we calculate arc length by "this" crude definition? $$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \sqrt{h^2+(f(x+h)-f(x))^2}+\cdots+\sqrt{h^2+(f(x+nh)-f(x+(n-1)h))^2}$$

Comment: Do you know Riemann sums?

Comment: Yup. Obviously.

Comment: You're integrating from $a$ to $b$ so all the $x$ in your formula should be $a$ and $a+nh=b$ which gives $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$ right?

Comment: Yes. (y). Hmm. OK.

Comment: Yes your formula is not suitable for calculation. it acts as a crude definition. A proper definition of arclength is at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/functions-of-bounded-variation-part-2.html Search "length of a curve" there. Like square root of $x$ is a number $y$ such that $y^{2} = x$. but you calculate square root using long division.

Comment: See the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to get our head around the fact that the number of summands is becoming arbitrarily large, even as individual summands are approaching zero. To put it in stark terms, consider the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac 1n$$

By the 'naive' argument, "Look, each term $\frac 1n$ becomes zero in some sense, so isn't the limit of the sum zero?".

No. Because the number of summands offsets the smallness of the individual summands. And in this case, that sum is equal to one for all $n \geq 1$ and hence so is the limit.

By the way, the sum above is one Riemann sum expression for the integral

$$\int_0^1 1 \ dx$$
which of course is equal to one.

---

*Added:*

Rewriting your formula, the arc length of a smooth function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$, with a step size $h = \frac{b-a}{n}$ is the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{h^2 + \left(f(a + jh) - f(a + (j-1)h) \right)^2}$$

This is equal to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{f(a + jh) - f(a + (j-1)h)}{h}\right)^2} \cdot h $$

In the limit as $n\to\infty$ or $h\to 0$, the inner quotient is the derivative and we recover the traditional formula.

Comment: Where is j in the summed function?

Comment: There isn't a $j$ in the summand of this example, but there are still $n$ terms being summed.

Comment: How will you expand it?

Comment: If $n = 2$, then $\frac 12 + \frac 12$. If $n = 3$, then $\frac 13 + \frac 13 + \frac 13$, etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of $j$ then?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Obviously, $j$ is a counter. If Simon just wrote $\lim_n 1$, it wouldn't really serve the point, don't you think?

Comment: $j$ is an index for the sum. To give another example

$$\int_0^1 x \ dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac jn \frac 1n$$

This is also not equal to zero, even though $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac jn \frac 1n = 0$ for any individual summand, an individual rectangle of area.

Comment: @Simon It might be a good point to mention that $\sum_n a_n$ converges implies $\lim_n a_n = 0$ in your answer as well.

Comment: So is $j\leq n$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a$ means $\underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{n~\text{times}}$.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Try carefully writing down the limit in your original question. It takes the form $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n S_j$. Even though each individual summand $S_j$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$, the sum of the terms does not.

Comment: So can you simplify my arc length formula?  (Forget about the traditional one)

Comment: See comments added to my answer